# Does Firebase Real-time Database only work within a limited area?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a blog on a website and I want to use JSON objects to store the blog post data because it's nicer than documents.

I read somewhere that Firebase Real-Time Data storage (uses a nice JSON format) is optimal for a limited geographic area. Does this mean that at further distances it will still work but with more latency, or will it not work at all?

Or is it recommended for me to just use the document style Cloud Firestore or MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realtime Database will work anywhere there is an internet connection.  The servers are currently hosted in the United States, so the further away you get from there, the lower latency you will probably observe.  It all depends on the quality of the network connection between the client and server.

Firestore has [several regions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations) to select from, if that helps your users.  You should benchmark with actual data though.